# Only screen lock when on untrusted networks?

Tags: lock-screen

I want to pull off something similar to: http://www.xda-developers.com/smart-unlock-trusted-wifi/

Basically when I'm at home connected to my wifi/wired network, I don't want screen lock.  When I'm anywhere else, I want an aggressive screen lock policy.  Does any system provide such options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable lock screen based on which WIFI network I'm connected to?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/848989/how-to-disable-lock-screen-based-on-which-wifi-network-im-connected-to)